# Catching system events in C Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, system

I am writing an application on Linux which requires me to catch system events like:

1. System reboot
2. User 'xyz' logs in
3. 'xyz' application crashes etc.

and need to execute some functionality based on that. For e.g.:

1. Run backup script
2. Run recovery program etc.

Can anyone please tell me how to catch system events in C/Linux ?

P.S: I am not talking about 'file system' events here :P

Comment: For the first do a Google search on "runlevels".

Comment: You can register a function to be called at reboot with `register_reboot_notifier`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept of "system event". You need to specify which events you need to handle and implement appropriate mechanism for handling each:

- System startup: The `init` process calls scripts from `/etc/init.d` during startup. The exact infrastructure differs slightly between distributions, but [Linux Standards Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml) [System Initialization](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/tocsysinit.html) should generally work on all.
- User login/logout: The LSB also defines interface to the [Pluggable Authentication Modules](http://pam.sourceforge.net/) library. You can implement a shared library that will be called during login (and also other actions that require authentication and authorization). Depending on what you want to do there may already be a module that will work for you, so try looking for it first. In either case I don't think there is distribution-independent way of installing it and even on given distribution you have to consider that administrator might have made custom modification, so the installation will need manual intervention by the administrator.
- Application crashes: You would have to instrument it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okey, isn't there anything in Linux like **inotify()** which listens to the system events and notify the application?

Comment: @Shrirang: As I said, there is no concept of system event in the first place. GNU/Linux, like any other Unix, system is built from mostly independent components. One takes care of the initialization, one of authentication and authorization, one of graphic user interface, etc. Each can be replaced separately and even sometimes is. E.g. the PAM library unifying authentication is much younger than Linux kernel. And while SysV Init is much older, it is now being replaced with [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) in some distributions (fortunately supports init scripts).

Answer (score 4):

I think you should consider reading systems logs - everything you ask about is logged to the syslog (for standard configuration). If your system uses syslog-ng, then you could even configure it to write directly to your program, see http://www.syslog.org/syslog-ng/v2/#id2536904 for details. But even with any other syslog daemon, you can always read file (or files) from /var/log just like `tail -f` does, end react on particular messages.

I'm not sure about catching application crashes - there's a kernel option to log every SIGSEGV in user processes, but AFAIK it is available only on ARM architecture - last resort would be to instrument your application (as Jan Hudec pointed out) to log something to syslog.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess reading system logs will have a huge performance overhead. Every minute we will have to process hundreds of lines :P But any ways I will evaluate this solution as well

Comment: @Shrirang: Actually it's a pretty good option. The syslog daemon is pretty flexible, so you can tell it to write the logs of specific events you are interested in to a separate place and you can even tell it to send them to you over pipe or socket. But you can still only react ex-post, so it might or might not be appropriate, depending on what you want to do. And of course you still need to start up from init script.

Comment: Performance shouldn't be a big issue here, I'm working on a project where we are processing syslog entries using perl script, we can easily process up to few hundred thousand lines per second. If you configure syslog properly - to get only what you are actually interested in - performance should be no problem.